# R: order the level of a factor vector based on the first number in the factor

Tags: r, sorting, levels

I want to order the level of a factor vector based on the first number in the factor.

Below is the example:

```
FC <- factor(c("R: 12.22 P: 170.0", "R: 12.98 P: 189.1", "R: 2.55 P: 286", "R: 12.22 P: 170.0", "R: 12.98 P: 189.1", "R: 2.55 P: 286"))

## the original level oder 
FC
[1] R: 12.22 P: 170.0 R: 12.98 P: 189.1 R: 2.55 P: 286    R: 12.22 P: 170.0 R: 12.98 P: 189.1 R: 2.55 P: 286   
Levels: R: 12.22 P: 170.0 R: 12.98 P: 189.1 R: 2.55 P: 286
```

I want the level to be ordered according to the first number in the factor in the example, i.e., in the order of `2.55`, `12.22` and `12.98`

The result will be like below:

```
## ordered level
FC 
Levels: R: 2.55 P: 286 R: 12.22 P: 170.0 R: 12.98 P: 189.1
```

What I am thinking to extract the first number in the factor vector, and then order the factor.

```
fistNum <- read.table(text = levels(FC))[[2]]

fistNum 
[1] 12.22 12.98  2.55
```

I then don't know how to continue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base

```
FC <- factor(c("R: 12.22 P: 170.0", "R: 12.98 P: 189.1", "R: 2.55 P: 286", "R: 12.22 P: 170.0", "R: 12.98 P: 189.1", "R: 2.55 P: 286"))

# Coherce to character for gsub
cc <- paste(FC)
cc
#> [1] "R: 12.22 P: 170.0" "R: 12.98 P: 189.1" "R: 2.55 P: 286"   
#> [4] "R: 12.22 P: 170.0" "R: 12.98 P: 189.1" "R: 2.55 P: 286"

# Get first value in each string
fv <- gsub(pattern = ".*\\s([0-9.]*)\\s.*", replacement = "\\1", x = cc)
fv
#> [1] "12.22" "12.98" "2.55"  "12.22" "12.98" "2.55"

df <- data.frame(cbind(cc, fv))
df
#>                  cc    fv
#> 1 R: 12.22 P: 170.0 12.22
#> 2 R: 12.98 P: 189.1 12.98
#> 3    R: 2.55 P: 286  2.55
#> 4 R: 12.22 P: 170.0 12.22
#> 5 R: 12.98 P: 189.1 12.98
#> 6    R: 2.55 P: 286  2.55

FC <- factor(FC, levels = unique(df[order(as.numeric(df$fv)),"cc"]))
FC
#> [1] R: 12.22 P: 170.0 R: 12.98 P: 189.1 R: 2.55 P: 286    R: 12.22 P: 170.0
#> [5] R: 12.98 P: 189.1 R: 2.55 P: 286   
#> Levels: R: 2.55 P: 286 R: 12.22 P: 170.0 R: 12.98 P: 189.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ?

```
levels(FC) <- FC[order(readr::parse_number(as.character(levels(FC))))]
levels(FC)

#[1] "R: 2.55 P: 286"    "R: 12.22 P: 170.0" "R: 12.98 P: 189.1"
```

`readr::parse_number` would extract the first number from the vector `FC`, we `order` those numbers and assign the levels

Answer (score 2):

We could use `fct_relevel`

```
library(forcats)
FC2 <- fct_relevel(FC, gtools::mixedsort(levels(FC)))
levels(FC2)
[1] "R: 2.55 P: 286"    "R: 12.22 P: 170.0" "R: 12.98 P: 189.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Ronak Shah. Following your answer, I have added another answer with base R.

```
levels(FC) <- levels(FC)[order(read.table(text = levels(FC), fill = TRUE)[[2]])]
```